# Delphi 4 error:- file not found:'htmlcons.inc'

Tags: delphi, delphi-4

I was trying to run/compile/build/ the Project  (Delphi 4).

I tried out this method also
http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/error_fnfCDO_TLB.htm

It consistently shows to an error

```
  "file not found:'htmlcons.inc'"
```

at wits end ,what to do?

Kindly help.

Thanks and Regards
-Vas

Comment: You're missing a file which is included by some other file in the project. But you have provided almost no information on what you're doing. What project? There is absolutely no way anyone can help you with this little information.

Answer (score 2):

Add the path of htmlcons.inc file, in the project search path.

**Edit**:

I don't have Delphi 4 to check what is the way to do that.

You should add the full folder path "C:\Program Files\PBear\HTMLComponents\Thtml\Package" where  htmlIcons.inc is, in the project option "Search Path", or in the Global "Library Path".

Project Options in Delphi 2009:
- Menu: Project | Options | Delphi Compiler | Search Path

Global Options in Delphi 2009:
- Menu: Tools | Options | Environment Options | Delphi Options | Library Win32 | Library path

It will work with any of both option, if you change global, it will be there for any project, or if you add only to the project option you are compiling, you can add a relative path.

Comment: Hi 
I tried adding htmlcons.inc to the Project.The path followed was
               Project/Add to Project/htmlcons.inc 
I am getting the following error.
              "htmlcons.inc is not a valid identifier."
My files are in the folder path
   C:\Program Files\PBear\HTMLComponents\Thtml\Package

 If the above approach followed is wrong,whats the correct one?

Comment: @vas: Check my answer, I added a more detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

htmlcons.inc is part of the "HTML Viewer Components" available (for free) from http://pbear.com/.

It is basically a Delphi based HTML rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your other question that you were having trouble with the PBear components, and updating your library path fixed it.  Did that also fix this problem?

Comment: Hi Bruce!
I am wroking on two systems(remote/local).So this error was in another system.
Here I ,uninstalled PBear and then re-Installed it ,mapped it and then the above error was gone.
But new errors cropped in ....then I solved them ....and more new errors crop up.
(I am dealing with enhancements for files that are already in use on the client side.)


Thanks and regards
Vas